# How to get the roles of a user in that guild, using discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Ok so i have written a bot of code, that when i do !userinfo, it shows the the info of the user

```
        case 'userinfo':
        message.channel.send("Getting info....")
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 1500 })
          })
          .catch(console.error);

        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author

        const userinfoyay = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('User information')
          .addField('Player Name', user.username)
          .addField('Current server', message.guild.name)
          .setColor(0x00FF00)
          .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setFooter('FREG FREG FREG')


       setTimeout(function(){ 
      message.channel.send(userinfoyay)
     }, 1600)
     break;
```

so what i want to do is add a field to it that says Roles: and then gives the roles that person has in that server.
How do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access a guild member's roles from the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, you have to use the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. You'd probably want something like `const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member`. From here, you can access the roles with `member.roles.cache` (assuming you're using v12).

Comment: Ok I just did that, and the comes as [object Map] instead of the roles.

Comment: @BadalSah The returned value is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).

Comment: But now how do I message the collection in the chat itself. I meant that I want to show all the roles of the person who sent that command. So I am confused.

Comment: Now that you the collection of roles, you can iterate over them. You could try using the [map() method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) here. You can format out the output however you want :)